# If two people are appending to a file with file_put_contents are the strings merged?

Tags: php

I have the following function to write to a log file:

```
function writelog($type, $text){
        global $root;
        $userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
        $tdate=date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
        $file = $root.'/logs/log.txt';
        $input=$userid."^".$type."^".$tdate."^".$text."*";  
        file_put_contents($file, $input, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

This function is used to add entries to a log whenever an admin of my database does a certain activity.

What would happen if two admins perform an action at exactly the same time which writes to the log file? Is it possible that the strings appended to the file would then be jumbled or merged together or would it always be inserted sequentially?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can cause the file to contain corrupted data due to race condition. It's not safe to rely on the fact that it only tries to append the data.

Instead, you should ensure that there is no concurrent access to the file. Fortunately enough `file_put_contents` has a special flag for this named `LOCK_EX`:

> Acquire an exclusive lock on the file while proceeding to the writing.

You can use it like this:

```
file_put_contents($file, $input, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Just make sure that your filesystem supports proper locking mechanisms. For example, I had trouble with my hosting company at some point due to the fact that they used NFS, whose support for exclusive locks is lacking.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. So if the file is locked does it throw an error, wait and append it later or just ignore the append completely?

Comment: It will wait until the lock i released.

Comment: If you need the function to throw error and return immediately, see [`flock()`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.flock.php) function and its `LOCK_NB` parameter.